# Blender can't open blend file using Append. Says "Listing Dirs..." but does nothing

Tags: blend-files, append

Maybe I have a bug here or maybe someone has seen this before, which is why I am asking.

I have a .blend file that I purchased, which has groups of trees in it. In the scene with my terrain, when I go to File> Append <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>  and select the tree Blend file, Blender just shows "Listing Dirs..." at the top of the screen and acts like it is doing something, but never does. I would love to be able to solve this problem if I knew what might be preventing Blender from listing the contents of a .blend file. Has anyone seen this before? Anyone know of a solution?

I would love to post the asset but since it is one that I paid for, I have an issue with posting it here for anyone to grab.

Comment: Sounds like there may be some huge files that are preventing the directories from loading quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad blend file.

You mentioned having purchased it, so I am assuming you downloaded it from some kind of online store, right? Have your tried downloading it again, file might be incomplete or have become somehow corrupted.

Is the file very big, does it contain a lot of images (like say textures for the trees or something) or very big meshes? It might just take a while to load all information.

Can you open the file directly?

Comment: The blends work fine in and of themselves. This issue isn't just happening to one blend file but multiple blends. The  blend file size are 80-100+mb in size. Blender can run indefinitely and never open them or in other words list their contents. The ones that don't work show 0 B in the Append from Library screen so I guess over a certain file size, Blender can't append a file...

Comment: If reported size is 0mb then there sure is a problem with either the file or Blender itself. Can those 0Mb files open correctly? Maybe you can open it and delete unneeded stuff, or somehow copy it to another file, or perhaps isolate only the objects you want and save-as and then try to appending from there, and see if that works.

Comment: The blends that show as 0 B open fine by themselves..really strange.

Comment: If you can open the file directly, try saving/exporting it to a new file or format, possible something is corrupt.

Comment: You might try viewing the internals of the file with a hex editor or other utility.  If they can open it without reporting file loading errors, the file format for Blender might be the problem.  Could it have been prepared using an older version of Blender?